# Conditionally joining two lists or taking the first and saving it in a variable

Tags: ansible

I have a role for a vpn server and some of them should be accessible to everyone, others only to admins.

Users and admins do not intersect, I want to use the variable `only_admins` that is `True` or `False` to toggle between these two.

I came up with this piece of configuration:

```
- name: Set vpn_users variable 
  set_fact: "vpn_users={{ users + admins}}"
  when: ! only_admins

- name: Set vpn_users variable 
  set_fact: "vpn_users={{ admins }}"
  when: only_admins

# works
- debug: "var={{ item }}"
  with_items: users

# works
- debug: "var={{ item }}"
  with_items: admins

# does not work
- debug: "var={{ item }}"
  with_items: vpn_users
```

Any tips to get this working? Or other approaches?

Comment: note you can use debug more effectively like this: `- debug: var=item`. No {{jinja2}}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax for `set_fact` is not good as per the documentation (http://docs.ansible.com/set_fact_module.html). You also use a lot of unnecessary quoting.

Here is a self-contained example that works fine :

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    users:
      - ua
      - ub
    admins:
      - aa
      - ab

  tasks:

  - debug: var=only_admins

  - name: Set vpn_users variable to admins and users
    set_fact: 
      vpn_users: "{{ users + admins }}"
    when: not only_admins

  - name: Set vpn_users variable to admins only
    set_fact: 
      vpn_users: "{{ admins }}"
    when: only_admins

  - debug: var=item
    with_items: users

  - debug: var=item
    with_items: admins

  - debug: var=item
    with_items: vpn_users
```

Try it with :

```
ansible-playbook test.yml --extra-vars '{ "only_admins": false }'
```

or :

```
ansible-playbook test.yml --extra-vars '{ "only_admins": true }'
```

Note that for debugging, you can print whatever var you'd like with the debug module. So instead of doing :

```
  - debug: var=item
    with_items: vpn_users
```

you just can do :

```
  - debug: var=vpn_users
```

(ditto for the two preceding tasks).

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work, didn't find out why the `set_fact` didn't work though:

```
- debug: "var={{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ admins if only_admins else (admins + users) }}"
```